# Spring API throw interrupt signal when using Thread.sleep()

Tags: spring-boot, java-threads, thread-sleep

I'm using Spring Boot to build my service. I have an API that will scan the database to update status. It follows:

- Step 1: Scan the database to update status
- Step 2: If have no data then sleep for 5 minutes then back to step 1

However, I don't know why when I sleep for 5 minutes, an interrupt exception is thrown and stops it.
So, how can I avoid the interrupt signal, or how can I recover this thread when the exception is thrown?

This is my code:

```
public void update(String product, int status, List<String> type, int maxRetry, int size, double hours) { //NOSONAR

  do {
    try {
      list = repository.getList(status, product, type, hours, size);
      for (Data data: list) {
        // update data
      }
      entityManager.clear();
      if (list.isEmpty()) {
        // sleep 5 minutes
        Thread.sleep(300000);
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
      log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      break;
    }
  } while (obConfigService.isInWorkingHours());
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you should be using a @Scheduled method to update the status.

Comment: I don't use @Scheduled, I just updated my code

Comment: This contains an endless loop - not a solid design pattern. How/where/when is it called?

Comment: We have a Job Management, this is called via API from Job Management

Comment: How is this an API? This neither returns a value nor does it perform a single action; it will lock the thread it is called from. This seems to be an XY-problem, and the context given isn't sufficient to give a remotely satisfying reply.

Comment: It is likely a job schedule, have a job management call it every day, then it runs from 9:00 to 16:30